# Failed: fields cannot be identical: '0' and '0'

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoimport

I'm trying to import a csv file to mongodb using the following command:

```
mongoimport --type csv --headerline -d gender -c names file.csv
```

However, it is giving me the following error:

```
Failed: fields cannot be identical: '0' and '0'
```

These are the first few lines of my `file.csv`

```
name,years_appearing,count_male,count_female,prob_gender,obs_male,est_male,upper,lower
Aaban,5,42,0,Male,1,1,1.016100647,0.900100562
Aabha,2,0,12,Female,0,0,1.039491315,0.718014678
Aabid,1,5,0,Male,1,1,1.054572395,0.51094514
```

There's no field '0' and no identical field. I'm using mongodb version 3.0.7. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your example worked fine when I tried it.

Comment: That's funny, I've tried with this sample of the file and it worked. It might have something wrong with the rest of the file, but I have no idea what or where it is.

Comment: I've written a detailed reason and solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41667696/1553014